# RegExp Same Argument

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to create a RegExp pattern. Salt text is like that:

```
Lorem --ipsum-- dolor !!ipsum!! sit amet
```

I want to match `--ipsum-- dolor !!ipsum!!` but don't know what will come to `ipsum`'s place. I mean text may be like that:

```
Lorem --asdasd-- dolor !!asdasd!! sit amet
```

I can match these two text with `/--.*?--.*?!!.*?!!/g` . Right, I know that.

But I want it to match when two arguments are the same. In example that regexp pattern shouldn't match anything from these text:

```
Lorem --ipsum-- dolor !!asdasd!! sit amet
Lorem --qweqwe-- dolor !!asdasd!! sit amet
Lorem --qweqwe-- dolor !!ipsum!! sit amet
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this regex with a capture group and back-reference:

```
/--([^-]+)--\s+\S+\s+!!\1!!/
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qep5Ht/1)

If `dolor` is a static string then use this regex:

```
/--([^-]+)--\s+dolor\s+!!\1!!/
```

**RegEx Details:**

- `--`: Match 2 hyphens
- `([^-]+)`: Match and capture 1+ of any character that is not a hyphen
- `--`: Match 2 hyphens
- `\s+`: Match 1+ whitespace characters
- `\S+`: Match 1+ non-whitespace characters
- `\s+`: Match 1+ whitespace characters
- `!!`: Match 2 exclamations
- `\1`: Match same text as group #1 i.e. Back-reference to capture group #1
- `!!`: Match 2 exclamations

Answer (score 0):

You can use a backreference, where the pattern matches a subgroup captured previously:

```
/--(.*?)--.*?!!\1!!/
```

The `\1` here means "match whatever was captured in the first capturing group". The parentheses around the first `.*?` make it a capturing group. For general education, if you had multiple captured groups, you could use \2, \3, etc. to match other groups besides the first.